# Rewriting a presentation in terms of new generators

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I have a presentation $\langle X\mid R\rangle$ of some group $G$, and some words $W_1, ..., W_n\in F(X)$ which I know generate $G$.

> How can I get a presentation for $G$ corresponding to the generators $W_1, ..., W_n$?

My idea was to form the presentation $\langle X, a_1, ..., a_n\mid R, A_i=W_i\rangle$ using Tietze transformations and then eliminate the generators of $X$. For example, consider $G=\langle x, y\mid x^{-1}y^2x=y^3\rangle$. I know that $x$ and $y^2$ generate $G$, so:
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle x, y\mid x^{-1}y^2x=y^3\rangle
&\cong \langle x, y, t\mid x^{-1}y^2x=y^3, t=y^2\rangle\\
&\cong \langle x, y, t\mid x^{-1}txt^{-1}=y, t=y^2\rangle\\
&\cong \langle x, t\mid t=(x^{-1}txt^{-1})^2\rangle
\end{align*}
$$

> Is this correct?

Comment: If you use $\mid$ to separate between the generators and relations (as you already did at first), then it is a lot easier to read. Also, you did not end up with a presentation in terms of $x$ and $y^2$, but in terms of $x$ and $y$ again, now with an undefined $t$ in the relations.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks. I've fixed those typos.

Comment: Yes, your calculation is correct on this example. This is not easy to do in general, but there is an algorithm to do it that uses coset enumeration.

Comment: @DerekHolt Just to clarify: the calculation *and the underlying logic* are correct?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. When I say that a calculation is correct, I mean that every step in the calculation is correct, not just that the answer happens to be correct!

Comment: @DerekHolt I mean when I said "My idea was to form...", this idea is the correct idea?

Comment: Yes, the idea is fine, but to eliminate the $x_i$ you have to know how to express them in terms of the new generators $a_i$.